# The meaning of predictor $u_{n+1}$ in the improved Euler's method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I have $$y\prime=9x, h=\frac{1}{2}, y(0)=1$$ 
And I want to find y(2) using the improved euler's method. And I know that it goes:

$$y_{n+1}=y_n+h\frac{f(x_n,y_n)+f(x_{n+1},u_{n+1})}{2}$$

What I don't really "get" is the $u$. Is it a sort of an replacement for $y$? In which case it should not mean anything considering the equation I'm given.

Answer (score 1):

Lets write it in a form that will clear this up.

$$y_{n+1} = y_n + \dfrac{h}{2} \left[ f(x_n,y_n) + f(x_n + h,y_n + hf(x_n,y_n)) \right]$$

In the second half of the formula in brackets, we substitute:

- $x = x_n + h$
- $ y = y_n + hf(x_n,y_n)$

When we are calculating the iterations.

We can also find the exact solution to this DEQ to compare against. The closed form solution is:

$$y(x) = \dfrac{1}{2}(9x^2 + 2)$$

Comment: What just happened? Are those two the same formula? If so, you just cleared alot out for me.

Comment: Yes, they are identical. Of course, your problem is even easier given we only have $f(x,y) = 9x$. In fact, are you sure you write that correctly?

Comment: @user100620: Yes, that is correct ($y_1 = 17/8)$, although you should not post questions as answers. Keep iterating a handful of times and comparing to the exact result I provided and look at what is happening.

Comment: Needs a thumb's up! +1